# adsense account for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, photo, adsense

My site is [spam deleted]. I got first approval for adsense 3-4 days ago and than posted the script in my site. Can anyone tell me when will I get the full approval?

Comment: Why does this post require your website's URL? Hmmm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official answer is 2-3 days.
http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76228

So it should be any time now.

In reality, the time varies.  A week would not be extraordinary.

The situation is much better than it has been in the past.  A couple years ago people were complaining of it taking months for the approval process.